# Why my PreferenceScreen is showing white instead of the default black?

Tags: android, background, preferenceactivity

I am testing my app but when I choose settings my preferences screen shows White instead of the default black theme. Just with my app because any other app shows the right black theme in preference screen.

Comment: Did You set any theme for Preference screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme">

    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

add the above code in value -> styles and
then add

```
 <activity android:name=".Preferrence" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"></activity>
```

in your manifest file it will solve your problem :)

Comment: WoW! Thank you Auto-Droid... Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to Vote Up your answer...

Comment: its ok you got your ans thats important i dont care about reputation

Comment: I am noticing that my background color it's ok now, black, but missing the thin division lines between the Items... Have you any idea what is happening Auto-Droid?

Comment: https://lh6.ggpht.com/tTot-qJS5fmmn9DYoOGU7zCG1Jsd7RV1jjiKvQyI1dIK1TLfAGNsr5xTIkK1t1svmG8=h230

Comment: I also had the white preference screen problem but when i added the above code it worked for me you can see the above link, sorry but i have no idea about your problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you using the Light Theme in your AndroidManifest.xml. For those PreferenceActivity set the Theme like this:

```
   <activity
        android:name="PreferenceActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
    </activity>
```